# Angular 5 Material Dialog box with header strip on top

Tags: angular, angular-material2

When the Angular Materail dialog box is added and by default it comes up with normal dialog box without any borders or any close button with top strip on it. But here i am trying to add the strip on top the Dialog box as shown below in the picture.

[image]

I am planning to show the black strip on top of the dialog box which should touch the above 2 corners. But the problem is if i add any div then i think its not good solution. Is there any Angular Material feature available as of now. So for that i have added the div on top of it. But i think its not a feasible solution. I have to add those strips on multiple dialog boxes. So can anybody help me on this?

The code is below.

```
<div style="background-color: black; height:30px; width: auto"></div>
<h1 mat-dialog-title>Hi {{data.name}}</h1>
<div mat-dialog-content>
  <p>What's your favorite animal?</p>
  <mat-form-field>
    <input matInput [(ngModel)]="data.animal">
  </mat-form-field>
</div>
<div mat-dialog-actions>
  <button mat-button (click)="onNoClick()">No Thanks</button>
  <button mat-button [mat-dialog-close]="data.animal" cdkFocusInitial>Ok</button>
</div>
```

[Stackblitz Code url](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mk42ag?file=app%2Fdialog-overview-example-dialog.html)

[Demo](https://angular-mk42ag.stackblitz.io)

Can anybody suggest me how to achieve this?

Something like this? See below.
[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just played around using the Inspector Tool and this can be achieved using this:

```
.mat-dialog-container {
    padding-top: 0 !important;
}

dialog-overview-example-dialog.ng-star-inserted > div {
    margin-right: -24px;
    margin-left: -24px;
}

.mat-dialog-actions {
    margin-right: 0 !important;
    margin-left: 0 !important;
}

.mat-dialog-title {
  margin-top: 15px !important;
}
```

Note: I haven't looked for any solution which is provided by the framework itself.

Comment: If you find any issue in this solution then let me know, then I look into this problem again. Thanks

Comment: I have edited it further as it was affecting the action items too. Please also add the below css that I have added.

Comment: Nothing is working for me. Its not working. Anyhow you have added the customized css for the template. So its not working. Any other inputs.

Comment: My friend you have added that css to the component, add it to your style.css. I added and checked on stackblitz and it's working. Plus there's a mistake in the css, I forgot add something, please copy and paste again in your style.css

Comment: Great its working. Can you suggest me on thing. I have to add this strip on multiple dialog boxes so for that if i keep on reusing the same code everywhere then so much of code everywhere so instead of can i create a component or any suggestion from your end?

Comment: Since it's in style.css, all your dialogs through out the application will be same and you don't have to do anything else. Plus if you wish to enhance it further then you can edit it from the style.css and it's done. Also if your problem is fixed then don't forget to mark the answer as right so other people could benefit from it.

Comment: One more thing when i have the dialog box form with so many fields in it then scrolling is not working. Any inputs from your end. See i have updated the stackblitz code.

Comment: Surely I can help you with that but I am driving. I'll be able to get back to you and see this issue in 45 to 60 min.

Comment: In your dialog-overview-example-dialog.html file, you have multiple dialog-content, you should have only one dialog-content under which there could be multiple inputs.
Check dialog-overview-example-dialog.html file here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mk42ag-zacpxa

Comment: Wow. Great !!! That worked like charm. Thanks mate. Keep up the good work.

Comment: Sure things, this is what I am here for... :)
Rating or no rating, we will keep contributing....

Answer (score 6):

Use the build in toolbar that is part of material.

```
<h4 mat-dialog-title>
        <mat-toolbar role="toolbar" class="task-header">
            <span> Dialog Title</span>
            <span class="fx-spacer"></span>
            <button mat-icon-button (click)="close()">
                <mat-icon mat-list-icon>close</mat-icon>
            </button>
        </mat-toolbar>
</h4>
<div mat-dialog-content>
  Modal Content here
</div>
```

Custom CSS for header

```
.task-header {
    background-color: transparent;
    padding: 0 5px;
     height: 20px;
}
.fx-spacer {
    flex: 1 1 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the code below. It's just a hack around. There is no direct support from Angular itself.

```html
<div>
  <mat-toolbar color="primary">
    <span>Edit User</span>
  </mat-toolbar>

  <div style="height: calc(80vh - 160px); overflow: auto; padding: 16px;">
    <!-- this 80vh height, you also need to pass in object when invoking the dialog from .ts-->
    <!--You body will go here-->
  </div>
  <mat-toolbar fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="end center" fxLayoutGap="16px" style="padding: 16px;">
    <button mat-button (click)="something()">Cancel</button>
    <button mat-raised-button (click)="something()" color="primary">Update</button>
  </mat-toolbar>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

From Angular Material docs you can use this directive on the area you want to have fixed to the top:

```
MatDialogTitle

Title of a dialog element. Stays fixed to the top of the dialog when scrolling.

Selector: [mat-dialog-title] [matDialogTitle]

Exported as: matDialogTitle
```

https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/api